# Parsing a string in python without knowing is in the string

Tags: python, string, parsing, quotes

I'm trying to parse a random string between a set of quotation marks. 
The data is always of the form:

klheafoiehaiofa"**randomtextnamehere.ext**"fiojeaiof;jidoa;jfioda

I know what .ext is, and that what I want is **randomtextnamehere.ext**, and that it is always separated by " ".

Currently I can only deal with certain cases, but I want to be able to handle any case, and if I could just start grabbing at the first ", and stop at the second ", that would be great. Since there's a possibility of there being more than one set of " per line.

Thanks!

Comment: And... What have you written so far in your code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
Docstring:
S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
from the result.
```

---

```
In [1]: s = 'klheafoiehaiofa"randomtextnamehere.ext"fiojeaiof;jidoa;jfioda'

In [2]: s.split('"', 2)[1]
Out[2]: 'randomtextnamehere.ext'
```

Comment: Good.  The second argument to split isn't necessary, functionally.

Comment: @wim -- Of course you are right, I was trying to show that you can explicitly split the string *only* on the first two occurrences of the separator.